# Your session only lasted less than 10 seconds

Tags: linux-mint, login, session

I'm running Linux Mint 17 and recently installed Torch7. Now, after restarting, I get a dialog that says my session only lasted less than 10 seconds and there's an installation error and to use a failsafe terminal. My `~/.xsession-errors` file contains:

```
    /etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
    /etc/mdm/Xsession: : 29: .: Can't open /media/.../torch/install/bin/torch-activate
```

`torch-activate` is not there during startup, because that disk is not mounted at startup. That line used to show up twice in the `~/.xsession-errors` file, but I took out a line in my `~/.bashrc` that was calling it and one of the error lines disappeared. One still remains and keeps me from logging in normally. Is there another file somewhere running the command on startup? I can't find where it would be called from anywhere and line 29 in `/etc/mdm/Xsession` is a comment. How can I get back to logging in normally?

Comment: Can you check `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile`?

Comment: I checked `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` and some files that they refer to, but no dice - can't find anything referring to `torch-activate`, even `grep`-ing through whole directories. For the time being, I've hacked a fix where I put a dummy file in the location it was looking at, but it would be nice to fix it properly.

Comment: Post the contents of `/etc/fstab`